# Webforms: How to disable a button that is inside a Telerik RadGrid in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I am new working with webforms. I learned MVC first. I have a Telerik RadGrid that has a MasterTableView inside and then, a couple of columns inside this MasterTableView. I want to simply disable some buttons in the code behind but Visual Studio keeps telling me that the buttons does not exists. In a Google search I found that the reason is because the buttons are inside the RadGrid. However I didn't find any example to access them.

The buttons are inside the radgrid and they looks like this:

```
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="72px" HeaderText="Acciones" >
                                        <ItemTemplate >
                                            <div style="width: 100px">
                                                <span  style="position:relative;" class="grid-buttonColor1">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">create</i>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEditReportDetail"  
                                                        CommandArgument='<%# Item.ReportDetailId %>' 
                                                        OnClick="btnReportDetail_Click"
                                                        runat="server" 

                                                        Style="position:absolute; opacity:0;  top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;"  
                                                type="button" 
                                                causesvalidation="false" />
                                                </span>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <span style="position: relative;" class="grid-buttonColor2">
                                                    <button 
                                                        type="button" 
                                                        style="background-color: transparent; border: none; padding: 0" 
                                                        data-toggle="modal" 
                                                        data-target="#MessageBoxModal" 
                                                        onclick="ShowMessageBoxWithMessage_<%= ucMessagebox.ClientID%>('Confirmación', '¿Está seguro que desea eliminar la tarea?','DeleteTaskReports','<%# Item.ReportDetailId.ToString() %>')">
                                                        <i class="material-icons prefix">delete</i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

How can I access those buttons in order to write in the code behind something like: `buttonName.Enabled = false;`

Please! This is driving me crazy!

Thank you guys!

Comment: Does the grid has server side databound event ? if yes I think you can probably access the buttons in there. Just a wild guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
    { 
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 
        Button btn = item.FindControl("img1") as Button; 
        btn.Enabled = false;            

    } 
 }
```

or

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if ("your Condition")
{
    foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        ((Button)cmdItem.FindControl("btnEditReportDetail")).Visible = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav por your fast answer. Your second example should help. Just one question. What suppose to be "cmdItem"? It throws me an error. You mean to write "dataItem" inseated inside the foreach?

Comment: Yep, I changed cmdItem for dataItem and now it works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FindControl` to find server control that inside of Grid.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = e.Row.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```